# Receive Cannot read property 'getContext' of null when using drawImage function on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I keep receiving the error,

> Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

whenever I try to use the `drawImage` method to draw a maze onto the canvas. It's not due to improper HTML formatting because my script tag is within my body tag. What I think it might be is that it has to do something with the fact that I am creating a canvas element in javascript rather than declaring it within the HTML.

Below is my code where the most relevant lines to the question are 19-38  starting with the `var = myGameArea` line.

```
var myGamePiece;
var coin;


function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(45, 45, "assets/dBear.png", 400, 120, "image");
    coin = new component(30,30, "assets/coin.png", 10, 375, "image");
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece.x = 400;
    myGamePiece.y = 120;
    myGamePiece.width = 45;
    myGamePiece.height = 45;
    coin.width = 30;
    coin.height = 30;
    coin.x = 10;
    coin.y= 375;
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 720;
        this.canvas.height = 406;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },

    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }


    }



function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.width = width; //this refers to owner of the function
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (type == "image") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                this.x, 
                this.y,
                this.width, this.height);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }
}


function updateGameArea() {

    if (coin && coin.x == myGamePiece.x && myGamePiece.y == coin.y) {
        alert("you have won");
        coin = null;}
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();

// need to figure out collision for this


    if (myGamePiece.x <0) {myGamePiece.x = 0};
    if (myGamePiece.y <0) {myGamePiece.y = 0};
    if (myGamePiece.x > myGameArea.canvas.width - myGamePiece.width)
        {myGamePiece.x = myGameArea.canvas.width - myGamePiece.width};
    if (myGamePiece.y > myGameArea.canvas.height - myGamePiece.height)
        {myGamePiece.y = myGameArea.canvas.height - myGamePiece.height};  

        if (myGamePiece.x < coin.x + coin.width && //hardcoded collision with coin
            myGamePiece.x + myGamePiece.width > coin.x &&
            myGamePiece.y < coin.y + coin.height &&
            myGamePiece.y + myGamePiece.height > coin.y)
            {
                myGamePiece.x +=5;
                var endGame = confirm("You have won the game, would you like to play again?");
                if (endGame == true){
                    location.href = location.href;
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            coin.update();  
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0; //sets default speed of game piece 
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}

function gameFunction() {
    //function that takes input taken from textbox, and 
var submit = document.getElementById("command").value;
var submitLow = submit.toLowerCase();

if (submitLow == "go(left)"){var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("go(left)");
    node.appendChild(textnode); 
    document.getElementById("functionList").appendChild(node);
    myGamePiece.speedX =- 5;
    node.scrollIntoView();
}
    else if (submitLow == "go(right)"){var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("go(right)");
    node.appendChild(textnode); 
    document.getElementById("functionList").appendChild(node);
    myGamePiece.speedX =+ 5;
    node.scrollIntoView();
}
    else if (submitLow == "go(up)"){var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("go(up)");
    node.appendChild(textnode); 
    document.getElementById("functionList").appendChild(node);
    myGamePiece.speedY =- 5;
    node.scrollIntoView();
}
    else if (submitLow == "go(down)"){var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("go(down)");
    node.appendChild(textnode); 
    document.getElementById("functionList").appendChild(node);
    myGamePiece.speedY =+ 5;
    node.scrollIntoView();
}
else
{alert("This is an invalid input" + "\n Only valid inputs are go(down), go(up), go(left), and go(right)")}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is running OK for me when I change the image URLs to an absolute path. I don't see any js errors.

I would recommend using a more robust design pattern using objects. This way your game would scale a lot easier.

The foundation of your game is based on your `myGameArea` which is responsible for starting/stopping the game loop and clearing the canvas on each loop which is good.

You have a separate function called `updateGameArea()` which updates the game components. The components 'coin' and 'myGamePiece' are declared in the global namespace so all the functions see them. This is not a good idea.

Take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ijackson/pen/pZmKZm) example I have created.

The example is using a Prototype Design Pattern. It has two classes: `Game` and `Component`. The Game class contains the game loop and entities (It could also contain your input functions). On each update loop, the entities are updated individually, then they are rendered individually.

This pattern allows for additional components to be added easily. And you could also use the prototype pattern to create 'subclasses' of `Component` which could each have a different `render` function.